# Sum and calculations for each customer in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

In a SQL database I got storage information for each user, for each customer.

I need to write a stored procedure that sums the disc usage (MB) for the customers users. When I got the total sum of all users for a single customer (totalDiscUsage), I need to perform a calculation (simple example):

```
x = numberOfUsers * 200
y = (totalDiscUsage - x) / (10 * 5)
```

After that, I need to write y to the database, and do that for all customers.

My question is how I can do this the best way?

Maybe using a cursor to go through each customer, perform the sum and calculation, and write the result to the database? Would that be a good solution?

Thanks in advance. Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you have a limited number of customers (i.e. pretty small number of iterations in your cursor) and you only need to recalculate at regular intervals, it sounds like an ok solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please - do not go around using cursors again! :-) SQL is set-based - avoid cursors whenever you can!

And here you can - easily. So for each customer, you need to determine the number of users first, and then do a simple calculation, and update the customer.

My suggestion would be:

- create a little function that calculates the number of users for a given customer
- create a second little function to do the same to calculate the total disk usage
- write your stored proc as a simple update statement that does the calculation

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateCustomers()
  AS BEGIN
      UPDATE Customers
      SET y = (dbo.GetTotalDiskUsage(CustomerID) - dbo.GetTotalUsers(CustomerID) * 200) / 50
  END
  ```

Seems too easy, almost :-)

Marc

Comment: +1. Cursors do give me that crawling skin, boogie-man type feeling ;)

Comment: Thank you Marc! That seems like a nice way to do it. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I agree that cursors should be avoided whenever possible, however there are (a few) times that they are the correct solution, and in this case there wasn't enough information provided to know for sure.  As to two functions which perform calculations (presumably via selects) I would also question the efficiency of this approach, as the function will be called - and calculated for each Customer (granted - mitigated somewhat by caching) which isn't really a set based solution either.

Comment: Yes of course it's set based - you just specify the set you want to operate on (count and sum) and let SQL Server do the rest. The looping through all customers and then all their users is inherently a bit inefficient, true - but don't make it worse by using procedural constructs when they're not needed at all....

Answer (score 2):

You can do an insert with a select query for the values such as:

```
INSERT INTO DiskUsage
SELECT SUM(Users.Usage) FROM Customers INNER JOIN Users ON somefield and somefield
```

or something like that. not 100% sure if that will work for your situation since I'm not really clear on it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

"The best way" to report on a given data set can't really be talked about without reference to how the data is stored, i.e. the relevant table definitions.

Unless of course you are asking how best to store the data to allow for this reporting, in which case you may need to reword your question.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitly be able to do this with a cursor.  There is also a chance you could do this in one statement with sub-queries or possibly pre calculations and a temp table but its hard to tell without more information.

Comment: Avoid cursors - no need here, really. Cursors are a performance-nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

write a procedure that uses the curse concept to find the differences between the sales of january and february for each item then calculate the total of the differences and pass it to the call statement as an output of the procedure

Comment: I think that maybe if you [edit] your answer and post some code demonstrating your suggestion that it would improve your answer.